# Why some phone number automatically verified

Tags: android, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

In Firebase console I add verify by phone.

in my activity:

```
    public void onClickSignUp(View view) {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            Log.d(TAG, "onClickSignUp:");
        startActivityForResult(
                AuthUI.getInstance()
                        .createSignInIntentBuilder()
                        .setTheme(R.style.Firebase_Theme)
                        .setAvailableProviders(Collections.singletonList(
                                new AuthUI.IdpConfig.PhoneBuilder().build()))
                        .build(),
                RC_SIGN_IN);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        }
}
```

When I start on Android 6 (LG) then

1. Show screen "Enter your phone number"
2. Input phone number
3. Press "Verify phone number"
4. Show screen "Verify your phone number" -> "Enter the 6-digit code we sent to xxx"
5. I success get code by SMS
6. Enter code and success login to my app

Nice. It's work fine.

But if I start my app on with another phone's number

1. Show screen "Enter your phone number"
2. Input another phone number
3. Show toast "phone number automatically verified"
4. Success login to my app

But I need always to enter verification 6-digit code.
Why I not receive sms?

Comment: If you have steps to reproduce a problem like this, please file a bug report with Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 0):

On some versions of Android the Firebase SDK and FirebaseUI may be able to automatically read the verification text message. In that case the user may not have to enter it manually.

Comment: This depend no from device , but from phone number. So, e.g. with phone_number_1 I input sms code, but with phone_number_2 (on the same device) no input sms code (phone number automatically verified)